# Why in my local repo, "git init" throws a fatal error, but is still creating the .git file? Then, "git status" returns fatal error "not a git repo"?

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

New to git, trying to follow an online course, but my ubuntu is behaving differently to the teacher's. I've searched for my error on stackoverflow and other websites. I found similar problems, but not the same problem. None of the answers helped me, so I made this new question.

In my local repo, when I enter "git init" I get:

```
error: chmod on /mnt/c/users/jds/documents/projects/testrepo/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted

fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
```

However, in the folder (as seen in file explorer) I can see the .git file has been created.

If I then run the "git status" command, I get:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)

Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

[Here is my ubuntu terminal, with the Windows File Explorer in the background (showing the .git file has been created in the repo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U1QF.png)

I am on Windows 10, running this in Windows Subsystem for Linux.

----------------- UPDATE ------------------

I deleted the .git file and restarted ubuntu as the root user. When doing the above commands as the root user, it worked:

> root@LAPTOP-ILK7ETOO:/mnt/c/users/jds/documents/projects/testrepo# git
> init
>
> Initialized empty Git repository in
> /mnt/c/users/jds/documents/projects/testrepo/.git/
>
> root@LAPTOP-ILK7ETOO:/mnt/c/users/jds/documents/projects/testrepo# git
> status
>
> On branch master
>
> No commits yet
>
> nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
>
> root@LAPTOP-ILK7ETOO:/mnt/c/users/jds/documents/projects/testrepo#

But why couldn't I do this as the named user? I checked permissions with "ls -l" and the testrepo had full permissions enabled:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Jan 29 18:06  testrepo
```

Comment: Just FYI, calling it the ".git file" is confusing. A Git repo has a `.git` directory, not a `.git` file.

Comment: 1. It's not git-related question 2. It's not a question for SO

Comment: It told you what failed, and what file it failed on, but you didn't look up the failing operation or look at the permissions for the file it failed on. You know how to look at permissions, ignored what it told you and went looking somewhere else entirely. That looks nothing like an effort to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why couldn't I do this as the named user?

Because your non-root user can't `chmod` file, as written in error-message. And "How to fix it" is out of scope of SO

PS - existing `.git` dir **is not a sign** of *functional Git-repository*

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The course demo I followed showed the non-root user doing chmod on a file, so I was mislead to think I could too. When I couldn't, I thought maybe I set something up wrong. So my focus was reading the documentation about set-up. I was looking in the wrong place. I am now going to find out how I can allow my non-root user to chmod as shown in the course I'm doing.